# How to include list view BackPack with other components or widgets?

Tags: laravel-backpack

I would like yo add something to the list view in order to make a report.
Is it possible without override the view and had some components or widgets below ?

How can I include the list view several times on a page ?

Thanks for your help

Answer (score 0):

You can easily add stuff to the List page using [Backpack Widgets](https://backpackforlaravel.com/docs/4.1/base-widgets#widgets-api). They basically allow you to include a view within an existing page. You can of course include a *custom* view (aka custom widget) instead of an existing one.

You CANNOT however include the list view more than one time per page. It's not coded in a way that allows that.